# iOS UNNotificationContentExtension (rich notification) display nothing

Tags: ios, notifications

I'm developing custom UI of rich notification with **NotificationContentExtension(NCE)**.

I've set up everything but the notification shows a blank screen after long press.

I found some related questions but it seems that no one knows the solution.

I've checked almost every detail, tried delete the target, reboot devices, restart Xcode, and so on...

[Please check this image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8r2qP.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.

It turns out that my NotificationContentExtension doesn't embed "UserNotificationsUI" and "UserNotifications" framework.

I added them and it works well.